# Unable to generate the correct signature using HMACSHA256

Tags: c#, .net

From the documentation:

https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#signed-trade-user_data-and-margin-endpoint-security

An example is provided in the documentation with an example key as show below:

```
secretKey: NhqPtmdSJYdKjVHjA7PZj4Mge3R5YNiP1e3UZjInClVN65XAbvqqM6A7H5fATj0j
```

The example scrypt is as follows:

```
$ echo -n "symbol=LTCBTC&side=BUY&type=LIMIT&timeInForce=GTC&quantity=1&price=0.1&recvWindow=5000&timestamp=1499827319559" | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac "NhqPtmdSJYdKjVHjA7PZj4Mge3R5YNiP1e3UZjInClVN65XAbvqqM6A7H5fATj0j"
```

Which generates the signature:

```
c8db56825ae71d6d79447849e617115f4a920fa2acdcab2b053c4b2838bd6b71
```

How do I do this in C#?

I have tried the following, but it's generating a different signature:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
               Encoding ascii = Encoding.ASCII;

               String secretKey = "NhqPtmdSJYdKjVHjA7PZj4Mge3R5YNiP1e3UZjInClVN65XAbvqqM6A7H5fATj0j";

               String query_string = "symbol=LTCBTC&side=BUY&type=LIMIT&timeInForce=GTC&quantity=1&price=0.1&recvWindow=5000&timestamp=1499827319559";

               HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(ascii.GetBytes(secretKey));

               String signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hmac.ComputeHash(ascii.GetBytes(query_string)));

               Console.WriteLine(signature);
    }
}
```

The above generates the following signature:

```
yNtWglrnHW15RHhJ5hcRX0qSD6Ks3KsrBTxLKDi9a3E=
```

Need it to generate the following instead:

```
c8db56825ae71d6d79447849e617115f4a920fa2acdcab2b053c4b2838bd6b71
```

Assuming I should not convert to Base64, but not sure what to convert to instead.  Also, this assumption could be completely wrong.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Notice the first key has 44 characters and the second has 64 character.  The 2nd key has padding which adds random character to the end of the key to make it harder for hackers to determine the real key.  the padding mode is wrong which is why the key are different.

Comment: @jdweng That's wrong. Both strings `yNtWg...` and `c8db...` represent the same byte-array. But the first one is base64 encoded and the second one is hex encoded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost correct, but you are encoding your resulting bytes to base64 instead of hex. So instead of

```
Convert.ToBase64String(...);
```

use

```
BitConverter.ToString(...).Replace("-","");
```